# sign Android Studio project apk as system app to use permission INJECT_EVENTS

Tags: android, permissions

```
Instrumentation m_Instrumentation = new Instrumentation();    
m_Instrumentation.sendPointerSync(MotionEvent.obtain(
                        SystemClock.uptimeMillis()+555,
                        SystemClock.uptimeMillis()+600,
                        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,500,1000, 0));
```

I wanted to try to develop analogue of TeamViewer using Android Studio. This code fragment works fine while the application UI is shown, I want to use sendPointerSync method while the app is on background, it gives me the message:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission
```

I added the permission, it gives the message:

```
Permissions with the protection level signature or signatureOrSystem are only granted to system apps. If an app is a regular non-system app, it will never be able to use these permissions.
```

how can I sign the application as system app?

Answer (score 0):

> how can I sign the application as system app?

With the same key as the Android system is signed! If your app and the system has the same certificate your app is automatically recognized as a "system app".

But usually you don't have the system key as long you didn't build and signed the Android system by your own.